# PHP to SqlServer, Getting the last inserted identity

Tags: php, arrays, sql-server, identity

I'm trying to get the last inserted identity in my Orders table in order to insert the same ID into a linked OrderItems table, for each item in my cart array. My Orders table "orderID" is my identity variable, but when I try to pull the most recently inserted value, the result is "null." The original INSERT query into the Orders table is successful, but for some reason the "SELECT  @@IDENTITY" query is not.

**PHP Code**

```
$ordersquery= "INSERT INTO Orders (customerID, orderDate, OrderOrigin) VALUES ('{$phonenumber}', '{$time}', 'online')";
echo $ordersquery."\n";

$result= mssql_query($ordersquery, $db);
var_dump($result);
echo mssql_get_last_message();


$idquery= "SELECT @@IDENTITY as id";
$result= mssql_query($idquery, $db);
$id= mssql_fetch_array($result)[$id];
var_dump($id);

foreach ($cart as $item) {
    $itemID= $item['id'];
    $quantity= $item['quantity'];
    $orderitemsquery= "INSERT INTO OrderItems VALUES ('{$id}' '{$itemID}', '{$quantity}')";
    if ($resultitems= mssql_query($orderitemsquery, $db)){
        echo $orderitemsquery;
    }
}
```

**Result**

```
INSERT INTO Orders (customerID, orderDate, OrderOrigin) VALUES ('(433) 943-4334', '2015-05-10 14:46:40', 'online')
boolean true
The statement has been terminated.
null
boolean false
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = "INSERT INTO Orders (customerID, orderDate, OrderOrigin) VALUES (?,?,?); SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()";
$resource=sqlsrv_query($conn, $query, $arrParams); 
sqlsrv_next_result($resource);  //note this line!!
sqlsrv_fetch($resource); 
echo sqlsrv_get_field($resource, 0);
```

Or - if you prefer "mssql_" extension functions:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO Orders (customerID, orderDate, OrderOrigin) VALUES (?,?,?); SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()";
$results = mssql_fetch_assoc(mssql_query($sql));
$lastid=$results[0];
```

`SCOPE_IDENTITY` is generally better because `@@IDENTITY` is across scopes - it's the last identity inserted into ANY table in the current session, so you better be careful with `@@IDENTITY` - you can get a value from a trigger or something.

Comment: `INSERT INTO INSERT INTO` is interesting. You might want to explain why `SCOPE_IDENTITY` is preferred over `@@IDENTITY`. And perhaps suggest learning about the [`OUTPUT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) clause.

Comment: @HABO sorry, just messed my copy-paste, double INSERT is just a typo. @@IDENTITY is across scopes - it's the last identity inserted into ANY table in the current session. SCOPE_INEDTITY is generally better. Gonna edit the answer to reflect this.

Comment: @SergeShultz Can you explain this?

Comment: @IrisSpik explain what? The basic idea is to place `SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()` into your main query. I'm just using sqlsrv_ functions instead of your mssql_ functions, it's a matter of habbit. I will add a mssql equivalent to the answer

Answer (score 0):

Oracle doesn`t have autoincrement. The best you can do, is to get the id first, then do the insert. You get the id like this:

```
$statement = oci_parse(OCI_CONN, "Select my_seq.nextval from dual");
if (oci_execute($statement)) {
    $row = oci_fetch_assoc($statement);
    $id = $row['NEXTVAL'];
}
```